# Is there a way to receive object, without having reference to it?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Suppose following code:

```
Object obj = new Object();
obj = null;
```

At this point, i don't have any reference to this object, but it's still on the heap, because garbage collection don't happens instantly. Is there a way to re obtain reference on this object, before it'll be collected by GC?

Only possible way that i seen so far is to use Unsafe, which provides direct memory access, but i will need to know where in memory exactly object is allocated. Also, there is Weak\SoftReference, but they are implemented by special GC behavior.

P.S. To predict questions like "Why do you need it?" - Because science is not about why, it's about why not! (c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is highly JVM implementation specific. In a naive implementation having memory allocation information associated with each object, you could find an object whose memory has not been freed yet and it seems you are thinking into that direction.

However, sophisticated JVMs don’t work that way. Associating allocation information with each object would create a giant overhead, given that you may have millions of objects in your runtime. Not only regarding memory requirement, but also regarding the amount of work that has to be done for maintaining these information when allocating or freeing an object.

So what makes a part of your heap memory an object? Only the reference you are holding to it. The garbage collector traverses existing references and within the objects found this way, it will find meta information (i.e. a pointer to class specific information) needed to understand how much memory belongs to the object and how to interpret the contained data (to traverse the sub-references, if any). Everything unreferenced is unused per se and might contain old objects or might have never been used at all, who knows. Once all references to an object are gone, there is no information left about the former existence of this object.

Getting to the point, there is no explicit freeing action. When the garbage collector has found *surviving* objects, they will be copied to a dedicated new place and their old place is considered to be free, regardless of how many objects there were before and how much memory each individual object occupied when it was alive.

When you search memory that is considered to be unused, you may find reminiscences of old objects, but without references to their starting points, it’s impossible to say whether the bit pattern that looks like an object really is a dead object or just a coincidence. Even if you managed to resurrect an object that way, it had nothing to do with your original idea of being able to resurrect a reference, because the gc didn’t run yet.

Note that all modifications to this ordinary life time work by holding another reference to the object. E.g., when the class defines a non-trivial `finalize()` method, the JVM has to add a reference to the queue of objects needing finalization. Similarly, soft, weak and phantom [references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/Reference.html) encapsulate a reference to the object in question. Also a debugger may keep a reference to an object, once it has seen it.

But for your trivial code `Object obj = new Object(); obj = null;`, assuming there’s no breakpoint set in-between, there will be no additional reference and hence, no way of resurrecting the object. A JVM may even elide the entire allocation when optimizing the code at runtime. So then you wouldn’t even find remainings of the object in the RAM when searching it as the object effectively never existed.

Answer (score -1):

> At this point, i don't have any reference to this object, but it's still on the heap, because garbage collection don't happens instantly.

It is undefined where it is, and it is also undefined whether or not garbage collection happens instantly.

> Is there a way to re obtain reference on this object, before it'll be collected by GC?

You already had one and you threw it away. Just keep it.

> I will need to know where in memory exactly object is allocated.

There is nothing in standard Java that will tell you that, and no useful way you could make use of the information if you could get it.

> Also, there is `Weak/SoftReference,` but they are implemented by special GC behavior.

I don't see how this affects your question, whatever it is.

Comment: I dunno, maybe my English is so bad, but the whole point of the question is to re-obtain the reference to the object after it was nulled.